# Parallel Subclassing in Python? Using Subclasses in a Subclass

Tags: python, class, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to make my program extensible. It's for a generic card game that will play multiple types of games.

I have a generic server, let's call it class `GenericServer`. It imports classes like `Cards`, `Players`, `Containers`, etc.

I also have a game specific server class that is a subclass of `GenericServer`, let's call this one `MagicServer`.

What I'd like to do is have the `MagicServer` load game specific versions of the classes imported by `GenericServer`.

```
class GenericServer(object):
    # imports Cards(object), Players(object), Containers(object)

class MagicServer(GenericServer):
    # imports MagicCards(Cards), MagicPlayers(Players), MagicContainers(Containers)
```

The plan is to have multiple game specific servers all as subclasses of `GenericServer` but also with their own versions of `Cards`, `Players`, `Containers` etc. I've considered just breaking the servers up individually, but since they share so much of the same code I would like to subclass them from `GenericServer`.

Any suggestions on how to work this out?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? You've described your setup pretty well, but I'm a little uncertain on the precise nature of the problem you're attempting to solve. Are you trying to cut down on code duplication? Automatically make `MagicCards`, `MagicPlayers`, etc automatically inherit from the appropriate subclasses? Something else?

Comment: @Michael0x2a It seems to me that OP wants to guarantee that FooServer can only use FooCards, FooPlayers, FooContainers, etc., and at the same time guarantee that BarServer can only use BarCards, BarPlayers, BarContainers, etc.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Yep, that's what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the server *generating* the cards, players, etc. or just serving/using them?
if the first... then the server class doesn't need to know what kind of card, player, etc. is used. Something else will create it and pass it to the server, who will use it using the standard Card (e.g.) API. This might be a lot easier to maintain and build.

But, if the second... then you could do it with class variables:

```
class Cards(object):
    pass

class MagicCards(Cards):
    pass

class GenericServer(object):
    cards = Cards

    def createCards(self):
        return self.cards()

class MagicServer(GenericServer):
    cards = MagicCards

gs = GenericServer()
ms = MagicServer()

gs.createCards()
<__main__.Cards at 0x3df6048>
ms.createCards()
<__main__.MagicCards at 0x3df6080>
```

These don't HAVE to be class variables - they could also be passed into the init function.

```
class GenericServer2(object):
    def __init__(self, cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def createCards(self):
        return self.cards()

gs2 = GenericServer2(Cards)
ms2 = GenericServer2(MagicCards)
gs2.createCards()
<__main__.Cards at 0x3ee5a58>
ms2.createCards()
<__main__.MagicCards at 0x3ee5470>
```

Which one to use? It really doesn't matter that much. The first is probably more straightforward if you are actually subclassing GenericServer a lot. If you are just using subclassing to differentiate the classes easily, the second is easier, and you can simulate the previous behaviour with factory functions:

```
def MagicServer2():
    return GenericServer2(MagicCards)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass everything, why not just subclass the generic server, then have instances of the other classes you need within magic server.

For example:

```
class MagicServer(GenericServer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards   = Cards()
        self.players = Players()
        self.containers = Containers()
```

This way your magic server class has a unique Cards instance to use.